# Drupal create report with data extraction

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

I have a Drupal website and I want to add a page in the admin menu with a form that will generate reports, based on the users that answer some enigma, and allow data extraction.

How should I proceed to create the form and make the requests? Should I install a module like CCK to create the form and then use another module for the data extraction (in an excel file)?

Thanks for your help.
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCK and views can make this easy for you, but doing this, will create answers as content on the site. I'm not sure if this is desired, if it is, you can go ahead. You would be able to create the solution purely be setting up the modules.

If you don't want users answers to be content of the site, but only accessible by admings, you should consider the webform modules, which will allow you to easily create custom forms that users can submit and save the data. I don't think that webform has built in support for views, or data extraction, but this could be accomplished in a custom module.

I have tried to expose tables to views in order to use it to do just this and have created CSV files myself in custom modules. It requires some special knowledge to do this, but once you get that, you can do it pretty quickly. If you have troubles with Drupal and PHP development, this will be a hard task though.

Comment: Thinking about it, I'm not sure Webform would help that much. I've played with it and don't know the point besides creating easy email contact form =(

Yes I need a form, but only to "filter" the data pulled out of some database tables. Only the admins will have access to this page, so do you still think webform is the way to go?

Comment: @Frank: Webform is good to put data into the DB and view that, but not viewing data from the db in general. You could look at [table wizard module](http://drupal.org/project/tw) if you need to expose the database, else a custom piece of code is probably the next best thing.

Answer (score 1):

The Views module will allow for creating of reports. It has several plug ins which allow for the data to be downloaded as csv, xls and so on.